# CORS not working on remote server, but working on localhost for ChatGPT

Tags: cors, production

CORS issue on production server:

I have a node server.js file that is working for CORS on all of my functions on localhost but when I deploy in production on my aws server, everything works except chatGPT API.  Has anyone run into this issue and is there a solution for this?  Below is a sample of my server.js file:

---

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
const cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)

const OpenAI = require('openai')
const path = require('path')
const {generateUploadURL} = require('./s3.js')
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
// app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//Body parser middleware (for sending back data in html)
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());


//Homepage Route
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/', 'index.html'))
})

//Setup database query function
const {Pool} = require("pg");
const pool = new Pool({ ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false } });
pool.connect((err, release) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(`connection error to database`, err.stack)
    } else {
      return console.log(`connected successfuly to database`)
    }
  })
const dbQuery=(text, params) =>pool.query(text, params);


//general database query <-- this is working fine from everywhere
app.use("/db/table", async (req, res)=>{
    
    const table = req.params.table
    const query = `SELECT * FROM ${table};`
    console.log(query)
    
    try{
        const result = await dbQuery(query);
        res.json(result.rows);
        console.log(result.rows)
    } catch(err){
        res.send(err)
        console.log(err)
    }
})


//Basic GPT response <--This is ok on localhost but not on AWS server
app.get("/getgpt/:prompt", async(req,res)=>{
    const prompt = req.params.prompt
    console.log(prompt)

    const openai = new OpenAI({
        apiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_API_KEY,
    })
    try{
        const response = await openai.chat.completions.create(
            {
                model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                messages: [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
                max_tokens: 2000,
                temperature: 0
            }
        )
        console.log(response.choices[0].message.content)
        res.json(response.choices[0].message.content)

    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});

//setup port for server
const port =3001;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running and listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: What does a request from your backend to the chatgpt API have to do with CORS? nodejs doesn't care about CORS, only browsers do ...

Comment: Please add the **exact** error you get, and also where you get it.

Comment: But one problem I see in your code: In case of an exception you don't send any answer to the requesting client, because your `catch` block doesn't contain any `res.send()` or similar ...